# GeoLocation returns “Location Unavailable” for Android 11 and Ionic 6

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an application Ionic Capacitor Angular that is simply getting the GeoLocation and displaying the lat lng on screen

```
async ngOnInit(){
    await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    }).then((resp) => {
      this.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;

      this.options = {
        center: { lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude},
        zoom: 17
      };  
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });      
  }
```

This runs perfectly fine in the browser with Ionic Serve. I have also successfully launched it on a device(Samsung S9) which is Android V9 (knox api level 27). However when I run it on a (Samsung S21 Ultra) which is Android V11 (knox api level 33)

I have the following within the AndroidManfiest.xml of the app

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

I see this in the documentation

Caution: If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, the system enforces this best practice [ *asking for foreground and background access in separate requests* ]. If you request a foreground location permission and the background location permission at the same time, the system ignores the request and doesn’t grant your app either permission

I have not been able to find a resolution to this issue. Can someone please help provide some insight. Again this is actual hardware and not an emulator.

Comment: What is the problem to use two requests?  If that is the issue..

Comment: Im not sure what you mean with two requests.  The only time i am calling the Geolocation is in the oninit that you see above

Comment: Two requests: `asking for foreground and background access in separate requests`. Not  a location request but a request to obtain permission to do location requests. A runtime permission. Like you will do to obtain those storage permissions.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this is an issue with Cordova and Google Play Services.  Version 21.30.16 of Google Play Services looks to have introduced this bug.

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4962

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a viable solution for Capacitor 2 until it is officially patched:

**Updated Answer**

As of Sept 10, 2021 Capacitor v2.5.0 contains the patch outlined below, but it is suggested that if possible upgrade to Capacitor v3 which also contains a patch and will receive bug patches unlike Capacitor v2.x.

**Original Answer**

> For now I've manually made the changes in [#4992](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/4992) to
> `node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/plugin/Geolocation.java`
> and used [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) so we can hotfix our app. We can then remove
> the patch if the fix lands in Capacitor v2 or when the day comes that
> we upgrade to v3.

The steps we just applied using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package):

1. Access `@capacitor/android` and update `Geolocation.java` using this PRs changes (https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/4992/files)
2. Run `npx patch-package @capacitor/android`
3. Update `package.json` with `"postinstall": "patch-package"`
4. `npm install patch-package` so dependency exists when `npm install` is run during Ionic AppFlow
5. Commit the patch file and changes to `package.json`
6. (Optional) If you get an error like ["cannot run in wd [...]"](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package/issues/185) add a `.npmrc` with `unsafe-perm = true` if you can't use a non-root user, for example when using Ionic AppFlow to build and deploy